# Using PropTypes to call a method from the parent class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a simple Parent->Child relationship and would like to call a method from the parent through the child component.

My child component is a grid of buttons, where each button has a name. Looks like this.

```
class ButtonsGrid extends React.Component {

    clicked = (product) => {
        this.props.clicked(product);
    }

    render() {   
        return (
            <div>
                <GridList cellHeight={50} cols={10}>
                    {this.props.list.length > 0 ? this.props.list.map(product => {
                        return (
                            <Button ref='productButton' style={{width: '200px', border: '1px solid'}} variant="raised" color="primary" onClick={() => this.props.clicked(product)}>
                                <div 
                                    style={{fontSize:'12px', display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', textAlign:'center'}}>
                                        {product.name}
                                </div>
                            </Button>
                        );
                    }) : ''}
                </GridList>
            </div>
        );
    } 
}

ButtonsGrid.propTypes = {
    clicked: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
}

export default ButtonsGrid;
```

The parent renders the `ButtonsGrid` component and should, per button push, log the button's name.

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      list: [
        {"name":"test1"},
        {"name":"test2"},
      ]
    };
  }

  clicked = (product) => {
    console.log(product.name);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container-full padding-0">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-sm-3">
            <ButtonsGrid list={this.state.list}/>
          </div>
          <div className="col-sm-9" style={{paddingLeft:0, paddingRight:0}} clicked={(product) => this.clicked(product)}>
            <ButtonsGrid list = {this.state.list} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

[This](https://imgur.com/a/3eGdO) is the error I'm getting. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never pass clicked prop to `ButtonsGrid`. Try this:

```
<ButtonsGrid list={this.state.list} clicked={this.clicked} />
```

Comment: Omfg it ended up in the `<div>` I feel like an idiot. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I do have a question though. Why does `product` still get passed to `clicked = (product) => {...}` in the parent if I call the method like `clicked={this.clicked}` ?

Comment: Because you call function with `product` parameter here `onClick={() => this.props.clicked(product)}`. So you call `this.props.clicked` with `product`. So the first argument to `clicked` is something you passed there.

Comment: I thought it was needed in the `clicked={this.clicked}` prop too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass function clicked as props to your ButtonsGrid, and if you are using this function from props, you don't need this function

```
  clicked = (product) => {
    this.props.clicked(product);
  }
```

Or if you need to use the clicked function on your ButtonsGrid, you should bind this function at the constructor like this:

```
constructor (props){
  super(props)
  this.clicked = this.clicked.bind(this)
}
```

and use it at your component with `onClick={this.clicked}`.

or you cand bind the function directly with `onClick={() => this.clicked}`

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't notice this.